How to Escape Brackets in dot files?
I'm generating the following graph:
strict digraph {
0 [shape=none;label=<<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0"><TR><TD BORDER="0" ALIGN="LEFT" COLSPAN="2">int l0;<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>l0 = 0;<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/></TD></TR></TABLE>>]
2 [shape=none;label=<<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0"><TR><TD BORDER="0" ALIGN="LEFT" COLSPAN="2">range loop(l0 = 0;l0 < 1000000;l0++)<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/></TD></TR></TABLE>>]
3 [shape=none;label=<<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0"><TR><TD BORDER="0" ALIGN="LEFT" COLSPAN="2">m[(l0*4)+1024] = 2236;<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/></TD></TR></TABLE>>]
4 [shape=none;label=<<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0"><TR><TD BORDER="0" ALIGN="LEFT" COLSPAN="2">proc_exit(0);<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/><BR ALIGN="LEFT"/></TD></TR></TABLE>>]
0 -> 2
2 -> 3
2 -> 3
2 -> 4
3 -> 2
}

but it doesn't get rendered because of the < on shape 2's for loop condition. how can I escape this character along with > and other similar characters?

Use &lt; for < and &gt; for >
